# Extracking Multiple Documents from one Page using Nutch

Tags: api, parsing, nutch, web-crawler

I'm using Nutch to Crawl APIs and Index the Data.

Using APIs, I can multiple "Pages" of data in one go.  For example, lets say I was indexing Movies.

I could query the top level and get a list of Categories like Action, Drama, Comedy, etc.  Then, I could query each category and get a list of Movies.  At this point, I can insert each movie as an outlink and have nutch crawl the details of each movie.

However, the Category call already gives me the details of say 10 movies at a time.

I want to be able to create the 10 entries in Nutch without having to crawl each of them.  Can this be done?

Comment: Note, I'm using Nutch 2.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Nutch to index only part of page content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630199/apache-nutch-to-index-only-part-of-page-content)